# Can't iterate through Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do this:

```
String regex= "^[\\d\\D]*([{]([^{}]+)[}])[\\d\\D]*$";
Matcher groupMatcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(command);
int counter = 0;
while(groupMatcher.find()){
  counter++;
}
//print counter
```

And I always get counter 1 and only resulting match for "{name} {do something}". No matter how I change it, here for instance I get {do something} being matched.

I want to iterate through all of the matches. How can I do it?

Comment: Your regex is anchored both at the beginning and end of input, it will therefore only match once...

Comment: Also, what do you mean to match with `[\d\D]`? This matches any character since `\D` is `\d`'s complement

Comment: Change the regex to `{([^{}]+)}`

Comment: You are using the `find()` method correctly by the way, it is really only one match.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change it. I don't know what is anchored.

Comment: You use `^` which is the beginning-of-input anchor: it will match the beginning of input and only that; as to `$`, it is the same for the end of input. Note that this is because of your "match all" character class that you get only `{doSomething}` (and not `{name}`): `[\d\D]*` will have matched _all_ the input before being forced to backtrack to match the rest of the regex

Comment: `(\\{(?:[^{}]+)\\})` if you want to match {name} and {do something},
`\\{([^{}]+)\\}` if you want to match `name` and `do something`.

The second case will actually let you get either one of them (with curlies at index 0, without at index 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should fix your `[\d\D]`: `\D` is `\d`'s complement, which means it will match any character which `\d` doesn't. Basically, this character class is equivalent to `.`...

Given that, let's replace the character class with its equivalent:

```
^.*(\{([^{}]+)\}).*$
```

After the first `.*`, the regex will have already matched all your input string. However, the matching is not complete: a `{` needs to be matched.

Therefore, the `.*` gives back character by character to the regex engine unless it reaches a `{` -- and that will be the `{` before `{do something}`.

Your first capturing group will therefore contain `{do something}`.

The first thing is therefore to fix your character class: I don't know what you meant when you wrote `[\d\D]` but it was certainly not "match any character"!

Here is a regex which will try and match all arguments within curly braces:

```
\{([^{}]+)\}
```

Use this regex in a `Matcher` and you'll have your matches (with `m.group(1)`).

Comment: `[\d\D]` is almost equivalent to `.`; `[\d\D]` will include newline characters where `.` will not in this case.  See [RexEgg](http://rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)'s documentation for the classes.

Comment: The intent was to match any character with it, but why did it stop on {do something} and did not continue to the next match?

Comment: Look at my answer again; your character class swallowed all the input before being forced to give characters back. This is why you only ever obtained the last match.

Comment: What do you mean by swalloaed? I don't remember I've ever read about it, I'm used to Perl regex (havn't tried it yet in Perl). If I change the last * to + , it gives me the first match, so why does it swallow other matches?

Comment: Try and unroll the regex, you'll see why `+` gives the first match. Java's and perl's regex engines are similar in the way they operate.

Comment: But I do understand why did the changed regex match the first one :( . I do not understand why didn't the original one iterate through all the matches.

Comment: Remember that the priority is to match the whole regex! If it is determined at some point that the regex can no longer match any input, the engine backtracks into the regex itself to try and match

Comment: I remember something similar I read in the Perl book, but I don't remember what it means. Could you please explain where in my regex it determines that it can no longer match any input?

Comment: Better yet: [buy this](http://regex.info/book.html), it is worth every penny and more.